# ExecuteQueryAsync not following through to the success/failure function, javascript

Tags: javascript, caml-query

I've got a function that checks if a list item (setting) is true and then changes the setting which it does correctly but doesn't execute the second ExecuteQueryAsync functions. In debugging it jumps out of the code after that function/line and never reaches the OnQuerySuccess/Failure Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function loopScript(){
    setInterval(checkSetting, 5000);
}
function checkSetting() {
 var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Biz.WebPartSettings');
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query> \
   <Where> \
         <Eq> \
            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
            <Value Type='Text'>PS-ImageSliderRefresh-ImageSlider</Value> \
         </Eq> \
   </Where> \
</Query>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    //console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
        if(oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes'){
            oListItem.set_item('Setting_x0020_Value', 'No');
                console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
                oListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
            this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailure));

        function onQuerySuccess(sender, args){
            alert('Setting changed');
            location.reload(true);
        }

        function onQueryFailure(sender, args) {
                alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        }
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:loopScript();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with creating `onQuerySuccess` and `onQueryFailure` functions outside of `onQuerySucceeded` function.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    //console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
        if(oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes'){
            oListItem.set_item('Setting_x0020_Value', 'No');
                console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
                oListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
            this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailure));


        }
    }
}

function onQuerySuccess(sender, args){
            alert('Setting changed');
            location.reload(true);
        }

        function onQueryFailure(sender, args) {
                alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

OR call the `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()` function like this:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onQuerySuccess(sender, args){
                                   alert('Setting changed');
                                   location.reload(true);
                                 }, function onQueryFailure(sender, args){
                                    alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                                 }
                                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `(oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes')` isn't true when you run the code.

If you straighten out all of the indentation levels using an IDE of some sort you'll get a clearer picture on where it falls out:

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        //console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
        if (oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes') {
            oListItem.set_item('Setting_x0020_Value', 'No');
            console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());
            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
                this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailure));

            function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {
                location.reload(true);
            }

            function onQueryFailure(sender, args) {
                alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        } // end if (oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes')
    }
}
```